# Magento error log

Tags: magento, logging

I'm getting a continuous error in my var/system.log file which I can't work out what's causing it.

```
2013-07-16T06:44:28+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Enterprise/Enterprise/Model/Observer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/vhosts/accessoriesonline.co.uk/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2013-07-16T06:44:28+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Enterprise/Enterprise/Model/Observer.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/vhosts/accessoriesonline.co.uk/public_html/app/code/local:/var/www/vhosts/accessoriesonline.co.uk/public_html/app/code/community:/var/www/vhosts/accessoriesonline.co.uk/public_html/app/code/core:/var/www/vhosts/accessoriesonline.co.uk/public_html/lib:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')  in /var/www/vhosts/accessoriesonline.co.uk/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
```

I've recently just updated the site from 1.4.2 to 1.7.0.2, all of the source files are there and compilation is turned off (its never been turned on). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is really strange. If you are working on a community version you shouldn't have this error, unless you copied some code from an EE version.
Anyway. Most probably there is an event declared in one of your `config.xml` files that does not find the model needed to dispatch it.
Look in you `config.xml` files for this text `enterprise_enterprise/observer`. If you find it, remove the event entirely.
If you find it in a core file send an e-mail to the magento team.
If you find it in a community extension you might want to notify the developer.

Comment: This hasn't found anything unfortunately, at first I did a full text search for the phrase 'enterprise/observer' in the /app/ folder and then in the whole public_html/ folder but it's coming with nothing. Is there anywhere else it could be initiated?

Answer (score 0):

Gavin, I have the exact same error in my `system.log` file. Marius's answer got me looking at the `config.xml` files of the extensions I use. I noticed some Enterprise Edition related code in the `config.xml` files for **GoMage** extensions (I'm using their Advanced Navigation and LightCheckout plugins). I wonder if you use **GoMage** extensions for your store as well. The error might come from there...

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone still needs an answer to this, the configuration string you want to search for is "enterprise_reminder/observer".

I found it in app/code/core/Enterprise/Reminder/etc/config.xml.